# How to Install tensorflow in anaconda prompt

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to install tensorflow module by anaconda prompt after the completion of 100% it shows the following error every time can any one help me in this case how to fix this problem please?

> Proceed ([y]/n)? y
>
> mkl-2018.0.1-h 100% |###############################| Time: 0:02:09   1.26 MB/s
>   mkl-2018.0.1-h 100% |###############################| Time: 0:01:05   2.50 MB/s
>   mkl-2018.0.1-h 100% |###############################| Time: 0:12:26 217.95 kB/s
>
> CondaError: CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/win-64/mkl-2018.0.1-h2108138_4.tar.bz2
>   Elapsed: -
>
> An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
>   HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
>
> CondaError: CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/win-64/mkl-2018.0.1-h2108138_4.tar.bz2
>   Elapsed: -
>
> An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
>   HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
>
> CondaError: CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/win-64/mkl-2018.0.1-h2108138_4.tar.bz2
>   Elapsed: -
>
> An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
>   HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

Comment: did you try `conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow`

Comment: Possibly check your Internet Options. Windows is weird.

Comment: bro Akshay i used     (conda install tensorflow) command

Comment: Bro Mateen Ulhaq i hae checked the net it is okay ...and even i have changed the net source but it still shows the same error..so please any idea?

Comment: Bro Akshay  if i use your command it is again showing this error:                                   Fetching package metadata ...
CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64/repodata.json>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
ConnectionError(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='conda.anaconda.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded...

Answer (score 0):

1. I am getting HTTP error when connected to virtual private network (VPN).
2. After disconnecting, I am able to install tensorflow successfully.

If you are on VPN, try disconnecting from it.